# How to save JSON elements as records in the database with Laravel?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, foreach, multiple-records

I have these JSON data I send with Insomnia :

```
[
    { "name": "Michel", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "Annie", "phone": "+213 93 783 28 72", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "Rory", "phone": "+16505551212", "users_id": "1"},
    { "name": "CESI", "phone": "+213 58 357 31 78", "users_id": "1"}
]
```

That I want to be saved as records in my database using Laravel, here's my code I didn't understand how to do it sincerely :

```
public function store(Request $request){
foreach ($request as $requests) {
            $contact = new Contact();
            $contact->name = $requests['name'];
            $contact->phone = $requests['phone'];
            $contact->users_id = $requests['users_id'];
            $contact->save();
 }
}
```

I got this error :
`Cannot use object of type Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag as array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently iterating over the Request Object, when you should iterate over its data with `$request->json()->all()`:

```
foreach ($request->json()->all() as $record) {
   $contact = new Contact();
   $contact->name = $record['name'];
   $contact->phone = $record['phone'];
   $contact->users_id = $record['users_id'];
   $contact->save();
}
```

Comment: I got this error by trying your solution ```json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given```

Comment: If you do dd($request->all) just bellow `public function` what is the response?

Comment: ```
$data = $request->json()->all();
        $response = [
            'data' => $data,
        ];

        return response($response, 201);
```

I get :
```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Michel",
      "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73",
      "users_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Annie",
      "phone": "+213 93 783 28 72",
      "users_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rory",
      "phone": "+16505551212",
      "users_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "CESI",
      "phone": "+213 93 783 28 73",
      "users_id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try `foreach ($request->json()->all()->data as $requests) {` in your original code.

Comment: Still having an error : ```Trying to get property 'data' of non-object```

Comment: Try `foreach ($request->json()->all() as $requests) {`

Comment: iterate over `$request->json()->all()`